# Connections, S4E1

Tags: knowledge

There is a timber a hallow is made out of, by some bemused by its uselessness, yet Vitruvius already pointed out the advantage of this timber being that it doesn’t rot. Indeed, a city was built upon this timber, similar to Venice, in which in ancient times a noble hostage was held - re-abducted, if you want. She was impregnated by a leader of a people who caused a global player a tremendous loss. This leader had a brother who worked for the global player. What was (presumably) the brother‘s haircolour?

<sup>Disclosure: A part of this riddle has been published in a local newspaper, I expanded it and adapted it for an English audience. The title doesn’t give any hints, it‘s just that this riddle reminded me on the show (S4E1 because it needs 15 characters, apparently</sup>

Hint 1

> I am a fan of Harry Potter, especially the later books.

Comment: is S4E1 a hint for the puzzle? thanks!

Comment: @OmegaKrypton No. The puzzle is really straightforward, every phrase gives you a solution, which in turn will allow you to solve the next phrase, and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Potential Answer**

The brother's hair colour was

> Blonde?

How I got there:

*There is a timber a hallow is made out of*

> In conjunction with the clue, this would be 'Elder', as the Elder Wand in Harry Potter is one of the three Deathly Hallows (and made of Elder wood)

*by some bemused by its uselessness, yet Vitruvius already pointed out the advantage of this timber being that it doesn’t rot*

> Some Googling brought me to a note from Vitruvius about 'Alder' which he noted was "of little value for buildings, but is exceptionally durable wood when used under water"

*Indeed, a city was built upon this timber, similar to Venice*

> Alder wood was most notably used for building piles in the Italian city of Ravenna (I guess the "similar to Venice just means the same country?)

*in which in ancient times a noble hostage was held - re-abducted, if you want*

> More Googling (technically Wikipedia-ing) brought to me Galla Placidia, who was held hostage there

*She was impregnated by a leader of a people who caused a global player a tremendous loss*

> She was married to and mothered a son to Ataulf, who was leader of Visigoths and caused tremendous loss to the Roman Empire

*This leader had a brother who worked for the global player*

> Ataulf's brother was Alaric I (also known as Alaric the Visigoth), who at one time was a member of the Roman Army

*What was (presumably) the brother‘s haircolour?*

> Google image searching Alaric the Visigoth shows that he was mostly blonde or possibly a red-head? The "(presumably)" in the question likely comes from a lack of historic account of his actual hair colour

Not sure how close/far I am, but it was certainly fun following all the breadcrumbs!

Comment: [Here is Vitruvius‘ note (Chapter 9, point 10)](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Vitruvius/2*.html). Ravenna is mentioned right along, so no need for googling that again. // Actually, I‘m going to accept your answer, I didn’t know there were two famous women captive in Ravenna, and everything else fits roughly as well. [For the intended answer, have a read at the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ravenna#Ancient_era)